# linear space and isomorphism - reasoning

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is linear space and $f:X\to X$ is isomorphism. Moreover, $\dim X < \infty$. Then:
a. $f$ is monomorphism
b. matrix $f$ in arbitrary base of $X$ is nonsingular.
c. matrix $f$ in some base of $X$ is $I_n$.

a. is true by definition.

c. is true. It is sufficient to get following base: (using fact that $f$ is isomporphsim) $f^{-1}([e_1, e_2, ..., e_n])$ and then express this base in base $[e_1, ..., e_n]$. Then, matrix will be $I_n$.

b. it is true.  Let's us note, that $f^{-1}$(base of $X$) = base' of $X$. it means that matrix of $f$ is in real matrix of change base.  We know, that every matrix of change base is reversible, so nonsingular.

Am I ok ?

Comment: No, because you don't use the same basis as a domain and as a codomain. Question c says ‘in some  base$\!\not\textrm{s}$.

Comment: Ok, I think about it. What about a. and b. ?

Comment: a and b   are true, as you said. For b. I'd rather say $f$ has an inverse isomorphism, hence its matrix (in any basis)has an inverse matrix (in the same basis).

Comment: If my proof for b. is ok ?

Comment: When it comes to c. you are right. Answer should be false. The reason  is that there are exists such linear map that they have no fixed point. Yeah ?

Comment: It's correct. Just a little tortuous for my taste, but it's only my taste. *De gustibus non disputandum*…

Comment: For c I now agree with you. I guess you were confusing with the cat that a change of basis matrix is the matrix of the identity map when domain and codomain have different bases.